# Multiple RTMP outputs with Azure Media Services

Tags: azure, azure-media-services

I need to relay the incoming RTMP stream to several external RTMP endpoints (facebook, twitch, ...). Does anyone know if it is possible with Azure Media Services? I can't seem to find any documentation regarding supported outputs.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not possible currently with Azure Media Services. We do not have an RTMP relay broadcast feature at this time.  We have several customers using external services like Restream.io though to achieve that flow.

This request has been on our backlog for a while and we will be looking at it in the future.